# What can deflect the Magic Missile spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

A few weeks ago, two of our party members got into a fight with an assassin.
All we know so far is that the assassin is a doppelganger.

During the fight, the wizard used *magic missile* on the assassin, but the missiles were deflected and hit the other party member. The DM didn't explain how the assassin did so.

We're about to fight the doppelganger again, and we want to avoid this scenario if possible. What can deflect or redirect *magic missile*s?

Comment: Did the DM say that the missiles were "_deflected_", or did they just say that the missiles hit another party member?  Asking because a doppelganger assassin sounds like a potential trickster who might try to get party members to target each other.

Comment: deflected, the missiles were directly aimed at the doppelganger specifically

Comment: You might want to ask "What can make it appear as though a magic missile were deflected when it wasn't".

Comment: but that's not the case.  the magic missiles were actually deflected

Answer (score 26):

The **[Shield](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield)** spell and the **[Brooch of Shielding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/brooch-of-shielding)** both stop **[Magic Missile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-missile)** cold, completely negating the damage. Some creatures (like the **[tarrasque](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/tarrasque)**) have abilities that can reflect **Magic Missile**, but the **[doppelganger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/doppelganger)** does not.

You're dealing with a house rule (possibly including a custom magic item, or property borrowed from another creature) or a mistake on the GM's part (perhaps misunderstanding the **[Ring of Spell Turning](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-turning)**).

In character, you could ask around, doing research to determine the existence of such an ability or item.

Out of character, you could ask the DM which it is.

Comment: Might be possible that the DM thinks a Ring of Spell Turning works on Magic Missile.

Comment: @Slagmoth Decent possibility. Added to the answer. :)

Comment: There's also the spectator's Spell Reflection ability. Doppelgangers don't have it and it shouldn't affect Magic Missile even if they did, but it's not unheard of for a monster to have something like that innately.

Comment: the Tarrasque's hide can deflect magic missiles. - Reflective Carapace.Any time the tarrasque is targeted by a magic missile spell, a line spell, or a spell that requires a ranged attack roll, roll a d6. On a 1 to 5, the tarrasque is unaffected. On a 6, the tarrasque is unaffected, and the effect is reflected back at the caster as though it originated from the tarrasque, turning the caster into the target.

Comment: @goodguy5 Reference added. :)

Comment: I looked up the Tarrasque hide armor and it does say it can deflect magic missile back to the caster but in the scenario I talked about the Missiles were deflected at the other party member,  not the caster of the ability.
is there a possibility that this is just creative lenience on the DMs part?

Comment: @Bwash Assuming you mean creative license, it's possible. That'd be a "house rule" I referred to.

Comment: While yes creative license was the phrase I was looking for, technically lenience works in the context